# Comparer that compares by int than by enum type

Tags: c#, sorting

Below is the implementation of a comparer that compares objects of type `Region` first by index and then by it's type. The sort order of the type is defined within the comparer.

I know, it's a trivial piece of code, however I am happy about any comments about the realization. :)

```
public class Region
{
    public RegionType Type { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
}

public enum RegionType
{
    DeletionBeforeNamedRegion,
    DeletionWithinNamedRegion,
    DeletionAfterNamedRegion,
    InsertionBetweenNamedRegions,
    InsertionWithinNamedRegion,
    NamedRegion,
}

public class RegionComparer : IComparer<Region>
{
    private static readonly List<RegionType> sortOrderByType = new List<RegionType>
        {
            RegionType.DeletionBeforeNamedRegion,
            RegionType.NamedRegion,
            RegionType.DeletionWithinNamedRegion,
            RegionType.InsertionWithinNamedRegion,
            RegionType.DeletionAfterNamedRegion,
            RegionType.InsertionBetweenNamedRegions,
        };

    public int Compare(Region x, Region y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null)
            return 0;
        if (x == null) return -1;
        if (y == null) return 1;

        var result = x.Index.CompareTo(y.Index);
        if (result != 0) return result;

        var xSort = sortOrderByType.IndexOf(x.Type);
        var ySort = sortOrderByType.IndexOf(y.Type);

#if DEBUG
        if (xSort < 0 || ySort < 0)
            throw new NotImplementedException($"Sort order for region type '{(xSort < 0 ? x.Type : y.Type)}' is not defined. Please extend the '{nameof(sortOrderByType)}' list." );
#else
        if (xSort < 0) xSort = int.MaxValue;
        if (ySort < 0) ySort = int.MaxValue;
#endif
        return xSort.CompareTo(ySort);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you throw an exception in debug only? I'd say that should be an assertion instead, if it's just to increase visibility.

Comment: Good point... that is probably more readable. Thanks.

Comment: Is the enum standard this way of comparing or can the order of the enum change based on what is being compared?

Comment: You do know that enum CompareTo honors the order of the enum declaration?

Comment: @Paparazzi: Yes, I am aware of that... actually, that was my first approach, but after  further reflection, I decide that the enum is not right place for defining the order for the comparer.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't define the numbers for the `enum` to define the ordering that this comparison should use?  It would make the sorting faster (you could just call `CompareTo` on the enums) and it would never need to worry about an undefined enum value.

Comment: Yes, because IMO it is not the right place for defining the sorting order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> private static readonly List<RegionType> sortOrderByType = new List<RegionType>
> {
>     RegionType.DeletionBeforeNamedRegion,
>     RegionType.NamedRegion,
>     RegionType.DeletionWithinNamedRegion,
>     RegionType.InsertionWithinNamedRegion,
>     RegionType.DeletionAfterNamedRegion,
>     RegionType.InsertionBetweenNamedRegions,
> };
> ```

Sorting needs to be fast, right? So how about using a dictionary for the oder lookup and not the *O(n)* `List.IndexOf`?

```
private static readonly Dictionary<RegionType, int> _regionTypeOrder = new RegionType[] 
{
    RegionType.DeletionBeforeNamedRegion,
    RegionType.NamedRegion,
    RegionType.DeletionWithinNamedRegion,
    RegionType.InsertionWithinNamedRegion,
    RegionType.DeletionAfterNamedRegion,
    RegionType.InsertionBetweenNamedRegions,
}
.Select((x, i) => new { Key = x, Order = i })
.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Order);
```

with it, the lines

> ```
> var xSort = sortOrderByType.IndexOf(x.Type);
> var ySort = sortOrderByType.IndexOf(y.Type);
> ```

can become

```
var xSort = _regionTypeOrder[x.Type];
var ySort = _regionTypeOrder[y.Type];
```

---

> ```
> var xSort = sortOrderByType.IndexOf(x.Type);
> var ySort = sortOrderByType.IndexOf(y.Type);
>
> if (xSort < 0) xSort = int.MaxValue;
> if (ySort < 0) ySort = int.MaxValue;
> ```

the index should never be less then zero. If it is, then there is an error. Its an enum and the property isn't nullable so I think the protection isn't necessary.

After getting ther `RegionType` order from the dictionary you should be able to immediately call this

> ```
> return xSort.CompareTo(ySort);
> ```

Comment: 1) Interesting.. I thought for few items (~less than 10), searching an item in a list is faster then a dictionary because it needs only few equality comparisons whereas the dictionary needs to calculate the hash value. However, after some [performance tests](http://pastebin.com/dKAm2E4U), it seems that the dictionary is always faster or at least as fast as the list... :)

Comment: 2) It is possible, that someone adds a new value to the enum but doesn't change the comparer. Therefore, it make sense to catch that error and give a meaningful error message. However, it may be better to use `Debug.Assert` as Cody Gray suggested.